# Is there a way to extrapolate a dataframe with dates in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to extrapolate data, where my x axis contains dates.

I have the following minimum working example:

```
df0 <- c('1-Feb', '10-Feb', '12-Apr', '20-Feb')
df1 <- c(10, 20, 35, 25)
df2 <- cbind.data.frame(df0, df1)
names(df2) <- c('date','value')
df2$date <- as.Date(df3$date, format = "%d-%b")

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df2,aes(x=date, y =value)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  scale_x_date(date_labels = "%d-%b")
```

How would I extrapolate 'df2' to obtain data in May, keeping the plot identical?

I have used `spline()`, but I cannot get my dates back after using it. Does anyone have any suitable ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: Formula edit

So you want to predict values in May based on the values you have so far?

Here's one way to do that, using linear regression.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df0 <- c('1-Feb', '10-Feb', '12-Apr', '20-Feb')
df1 <- c(10, 20, 35, 25)
df2 <- cbind.data.frame(df0, df1)
names(df2) <- c('date','value')

df2 <- df2 %>%
  mutate(date = as.Date(date, format = "%d-%b"),
         date = ymd(date)) %>%
  as_tibble()

ggplot(df2,aes(x=date, y =value)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  scale_x_date(date_labels = "%d-%b")

#make your linear regression model
model <- lm(value ~ date,data=df2)

#predict values for new dates in May
new_dates <- tibble(date=ymd(c('2019-05-01','2019-05-30')))
pred_vals <- predict(model,new_dates)

future_vals <- tibble(date = new_dates$date,
                    value = pred_vals)

#combine predicted values with observed
df3 <- bind_rows(df2,future_vals)

#chart the new combination
ggplot(df3,aes(x=date, y =value)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  scale_x_date(date_labels = "%d-%b")
```

Comment: I do not think you're using a logistic regression, if you do not specify the family in `glm()`. In other hands, if you'd like to use the linear regression, I suppose it's better use `lm()`.

Comment: the family argument defaults to Gaussian in `glm()`

Comment: Yes, but why to use a `glm()` when you've `lm()`? Just asking, maybe it's better to use `glm()`. However, it's not definetely a logit. Also you're doing a regression with date and values, it seems rather weird, monovariate time series analysis have a quite different approach (and probably the biggest issue with your approach, maybe I'm wrong).

Comment: Yes, I think you're right, I didn't really think this one through that much before typing out an answer. I just checked with lm() and the predicted values are the same. Tbh the OP can just follow my approach and use lm().